# BottomBar doesn't remain stack because of Listview

Tags: flutter

I am making the Homepage UI for my app and I am using a Listview to make my UI scrollable but it affects my bottom navigation bar that is in the same widget with the rest of widgets , what should i add to my code to make my bottom navigation bar( BarDetail () ) stack ? Where i should move the barDetail in the code?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Tariffo',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'SignPainter',
                  fontSize: 45)),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_weak),
              onPressed: () async {
                String scaning = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
                setState(() {
                  qrResult = scaning;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.perm_identity,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StoryProfile()),
                  );
                }),
          ],
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
      body: ListView(
              controller: widget.scrollController,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: SearchBar<Post>(
                    searchBarPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10,
                    ),
                    headerPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    listPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    onSearch: _getALlPosts,
                    searchBarController: _searchBarController,
                    placeHolder: Text(""),
                    cancellationWidget: Text("Cancel"),
                    emptyWidget: Text("empty"),
                    indexedScaledTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                        ScaledTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
                    onCancelled: () {
                      print("Cancelled triggered");
                    },
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    onItemFound: (Post post, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(post.title),
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          subtitle: Text(post.body),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Detail()));
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                HelloText(),
    
                CategoriesScroller(),
                TopText(),
               
                BarDetail()
             
              ]),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after body widget , put your BarDetail() after bottomNavigationBar:
for example and it will stick to the bottom.

```
body: ListView(),

bottomNavigationBar:BarDetail(),
```